# Is there a PMD/Checkstyle/Findbugs to Sonar rule mapping?

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I have a set of PMD, Checkstyle and FindBugs rules that I would like to transfer to Sonar rules.

Is there a way to map these PMD, Checkstyle and FindBugs rules to Sonar ones ?

Apparently [dist.sonarsource.com](https://dist.sonarsource.com) "stored 3rd-party tools rules coverage" but it "now redirects all requests to [www.sonarsource.com](https://www.sonarsource.com)". And Sonar team "stopped re-generating those reports a while ago". Is there a way to get such a mapping ?

---

I am well aware that my question is similar to [one asked on SonarSource community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/where-is-dist-sonarsource-com-content/5353), but [last question](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/where-is-dist-sonarsource-com-content/5353) did not receive an answer and I thought that a stackoverflow question might have more visibility (both for me and for people seeking the same info in the future).